# Why long a position when the acutal price is higher than the predicted price? (Kalman filter for pairs trading)

Tags: pairs-trading, kalman

In this paper [Elliott, R., van der Hoek, J. and Malcolm, W. (2005) Pairs Trading.](https://www.scirp.org/(S(351jmbntvnsjt1aadkposzje))/reference/ReferencesPapers.aspx?ReferenceID=1687852), the spread (state process) is assumed to follow a mean reverting process $x_{k+1}-x_k=(a-bx_k)\tau+\sigma\sqrt{\tau}\varepsilon_{k+1}$, and the observed spread is assumed to follow a (observation) process $y_k=x_k+Dw_k$.

In section 2.3, the authors have mensioned that "if $y_k>\hat{x}_{k|k-1}=E[x_k|\sigma(y_0,\cdots,y_{k-1})]$ then the spread is regarded as too large, and the trader could take a long position in the spread portfolio and profit when a correction occurs."

I want to ask why this trading strategy is reasonable. If $y_k>\hat{x}_{k|k-1}=E[x_k|\sigma(y_0,\cdots,y_{k-1})]$, I think that the predicted spread at time $k$ is smaller than oberserved spead, so the price is high right now and it will go down eventually since it is assumed to be mean reverting, so maybe I will short the position.

Appreciate any suggestion and comments.

Comment: Hi Steven: I was unable to obtain the paper but that sounds like a typo.

Comment: If the spread $y>y_0$ is deemed large compared to some $y_0$, then $e^{-y}<e^{-y_0}$ - the price is comparatively low.

Comment: @kermittfrog: Hi and thanks but I thought the spread was the difference in prices ? Why are you taking the negative of the exponential ?  Must be too late in the evening for me :).

Comment: Hi, I truly thought interpreted spread as in "interest rate spread", not in price spread. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Kermittfrog I think the spead here means price difference, if we have two stocks their prices are cointegrated, then we can trade its spread, its called pairs trading.

Comment: @markleeds I can still click the link.

Comment: Steven Lu: Yes. That was my fault. I thought it was one of those cases where the publisher made you pay for the paper. But it's not.  Thanks. Kermittfrog: Good point. I'm not sure myself which probably means that I should read the paper !!!!!!! I'll read it but no time at this exact moment.

Comment: Steven Lu: I read enough of the paper to possibly make some headway. My take as far as your question is that the spread that is being created is not between two stocks but between the sap 500 log price and the particular stock's log price. So, in that case, the reference point flips ( the stock log price is in the bottom ) and what they're saying is probably not a typo due to the way that the spread is being defined. That's usually not how pairs trading is done but I would just think of their methodology as a  pairs trading variant. The idea is that the stock is cointegrated with the market.

Comment: Steven: Note that the paper is not so clear, ( atleast to me ), so above is partially based on what I read and partially based on conjecture. But the formulae that were provided make me lean towards the spread being defined in the opposite way: market price - stock price.